# 404 error on images and css with tomcat server

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat

I'm doing a java ee project with eclipse running on tomcat server.
My webpages are working but when i try to put images, I've got a 404 error. 
Sooner everything was working fine and I don't know why but now I can't open any images or load a css file.
I've searched on the forums but nothing has helped me.
I've try every path I've seen and not a single worked.

I've got multiple servlet and this how I define the one with the image :

```
<servlet>
 <javaee:description></javaee:description>
 <javaee:display-name>Products</javaee:display-name>
  <servlet-name>Products</servlet-name>
  <servlet-class>Products</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>Products</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>/Products</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

This is the line with the path that used to work, the path that I found on the properties of the image:

`<img border="1" src="/Jweb/images/jambon.jpg" height="667" width="1000" alt="${product.name}" title="${product.name}">`

Comment: Can you remove '/' from beginning of "Jweb" and try again?

Comment: I've tried it, that's not the answer...

Answer (score 0):

If application not get image at provided path it will give you `404` error.

You can use `request.getContextPath()` it will give you your application root path. then you have to give your folder location inside root of application. If `Jweb` is in your root directory then following code will work for you.

```
  <img border="1" src="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/Jweb/images/jambon.jpg" height="667" width="1000" alt="${product.name}" title="${product.name}">
```

Comment: This isn't working. When I watch the source code, the path built is "/Jweb/images/jambon.jpg". The same path as the one I put the hard way. And Jweb is the name of the application `request.getContextPath()` return `/Jweb/`.

Comment: check that your image present there and it should be `jpg` not `JPG` some time case of extension create problem.

Comment: This isn't working neither. It's not an extension problem since this path used to work.